# "Event loop is closed! Is Playwright already stopped?"

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

### Context

After initialisation of a playwright browser object in function `initialise_playwright_browsercontroller`, I try to use its `Page` object in another function. However, that yields get error:

> "Event loop is closed! Is Playwright already stopped?"

If I use the `Page` object in the same function (and `with` statement) in which it is created, the error does not occur.

### MWE

Below is the an MWE that demonstrates the error:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from playwright.sync_api._generated import Locator  # type: ignore[import]
from playwright.sync_api._generated import Browser, Page
from typeguard import typechecked


@typechecked
def initialise_playwright_browsercontroller(
    *,
    start_url: str,
) -> tuple[Browser, Page]:
    """Creates a Playwright browser, opens a new page, and navigates to a
    specified URL.

    Returns:
        tuple[Browser, Page]: A tuple containing the browser and page objects.
    """
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        for browser_type in [p.chromium, p.firefox, p.webkit]:
            if (
                browser_type.name != "webkit"
                and browser_type.name == "firefox"
            ):
                browser = browser_type.launch()

                # Create a new page and navigate to the URL
                page = browser.new_page()
                page.goto(start_url)

                # Return the browser and page objects
                return browser, page
    raise ValueError("Error: Could not find browser.")


@typechecked
def do_something_on_webpage() -> None:
    """Tries to do something with the object received from the the browser."""
    # Declare the browser and page objects.
    browser: Browser
    page: Page

    # Specify the website to go to.
    start_url: str = "https://github.com"
    browser, page = initialise_playwright_browsercontroller(
        start_url=start_url
    )
    print(f"page url = {page.url}")

    sign_in_button: Locator = page.locator("Sign in")
    sign_in_button.click()
    print("Done.")


do_something_on_webpage()
```

### Question

How can I create the `Page` object elsewhere, and pass it around and use it in other functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use context manager, then you should use `yield` instead of `return`

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from playwright.sync_api._generated import Locator  # type: ignore[import]
from playwright.sync_api._generated import Browser, Page
from typeguard import typechecked
import contextlib


@typechecked
@contextlib.contextmanager
def initialise_playwright_browsercontroller(
    *,
    start_url: str,
) -> tuple[Browser, Page]:
    """Creates a Playwright browser, opens a new page, and navigates to a
    specified URL.

    Returns:
        tuple[Browser, Page]: A tuple containing the browser and page objects.
    """
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        for browser_type in [p.chromium, p.firefox, p.webkit]:
            if (
                browser_type.name != "webkit"
                and browser_type.name == "firefox"
            ):
                browser = browser_type.launch()

                # Create a new page and navigate to the URL
                page = browser.new_page()
                page.goto(start_url)

                # Return the browser and page objects
                yield browser, page
                return
    


@typechecked
def do_something_on_webpage() -> None:
    """Tries to do something with the object received from the the browser."""   
    # Specify the website to go to.
    start_url: str = "https://github.com"
    with initialise_playwright_browsercontroller(
        start_url=start_url
    ) as (browser, page):
        print(f"page url = {page.url}")
        sign_in_button: Locator = page.locator("Sign in")
        sign_in_button.click()
        print("Done.")


do_something_on_webpage()
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73055442/7437143) answer, in the following format:

```py
"""Gets the Playwright website controller and opens it. Prerequisites: pip
install pytest-playwright playwright install.

(Or with anaconda:) conda config --add channels conda-forge conda config
--add channels microsoft conda install playwright
"""

from typing import Optional

from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from playwright.sync_api._generated import Browser, Locator, Page, Playwright
from playwright_stealth import stealth_sync  # type: ignore[import]
from typeguard import typechecked

@typechecked
def initialise_playwright_browsercontroller(
    start_url: str,
    browsertype:str,
    headless:Optional[bool]=False,
    stealthmode:Optional[bool]=True,
) -> tuple[Playwright, Page]:
    """
    Creates a Playwright browser, opens a new page, and navigates to a
    specified URL.

    Important, call playwright.stop() once you are done.
    
    Returns:
        tuple[Browser, Page]: A tuple containing the browser and page objects.
    """

    playwright:Playwright = sync_playwright().start()
    if browsertype == "firefox":
        browser:Browser = playwright.firefox.launch(headless=headless)
    if browsertype == "chromium":
        browser:Browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=headless)
    if browsertype == "safari":
        raise NotImplementedError("Error, did not implement webkit launch.")
    
    page:Page = browser.new_page()
    if stealthmode:    
        stealth_sync(page)
    page.goto(start_url)
    
    return playwright, page
```

Then I call it using:

```py
page: Page
playwright, page = initialise_playwright_browsercontroller(
    start_url="https://www.some_website.com",
    browsertype="firefox",
    headless=False,
    stealthmode=True,
)
playwright.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `with` block managing the Playwright resource closes when you return from the function it's in. A more minimal example:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()

page = browser.new_page()  # playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Event loop is closed! Is Playwright already stopped?
```

or perhaps:

```py
def initialize():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        return p.chromium.launch()

initialize().new_page()  # playwright._impl._api_types.Error ...
```

Here are some possible solutions:

1. Keep the `with` block in scope by moving it outside the function, passing a callback into `initialise_playwright_browsercontroller`, calling the work logic once the browser is open from `initialise_playwright_browsercontroller`, etc.
2. Use Playwright without `with` and close it manually as described in the following threads:

   - [How to start playwright outside 'with' without context managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73043207/how-to-start-playwright-outside-with-without-context-managers)
   - [can i run playwright outside of 'with'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72653869/can-i-run-playwright-outside-of-with)
3. Decorate your function with [`@contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77135532/6243352). You'll still need to use `with` in the caller, but this abstracts away directly managing the Playwright resource.

The first option might look like (in simplified form):

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def initialize(p):
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    return browser, page


def do_work_on_page(page):
    page.goto("https://www.example.com")
    return page.locator("h1").text_content()


def do_something_on_webpage():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser, page = initialize(p)
        return do_work_on_page(page)


print(do_something_on_webpage())  # => Example Domain
```

Comment: Thank you, the first url you gave on point 2 of your answer was the solution I used. I will mark this question as a duplicate.