# Playwright: Unable to get browser in second step Behave Cucumber Framework

Tags: python, cucumber, playwright, playwright-python

Here is my code I am using Python on Playwright as I previously used the selenium its working when you only call the `context.driver` in second step but on playwright it's returning me an error

```
File "features\steps\Login.py", line 14, in click_button
phoneBTN.click()
File "D:\Playwright\venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_generated.py", line 14764, in click
self._sync(`your`your text` text`
File "D:\Playwright\venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_sync_base.py", line 102, in _sync
raise Error("Event loop is closed! Is Playwright already stopped?")
playwright._impl._errors.Error: Event loop is closed! Is Playwright already stopped?
```

```
from behave import given, then
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

@given("the user navigates to the your website")
def navigate_to_your_website(context):
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        context.page = browser.new_page()
        context.page.goto("https://website.com.pk/")

@then("the website homepage is displayed")
def click_button(context):
        phoneBTN = context.page.locator(".non-auth-section .Continue-with-Phone-Number")
        phoneBTN.click()
        otpBTN = context.page.locator("#otp-number")
        otpBTN.click()
```

I am working on Playwright I have tried it by using without steps it's working fine when I am using it in steps it's not working please help.

Comment: Looks like the 'Then'-step ends abruptly with the click of the #opt-number-button? This should perhaps be a 'When'-step instead? You should try to make an assertion in the 'Then' and wait for it to be checked.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cucumber, but using a `with` block doesn't seem right here, because the browser will close as soon as the `with` block ends. See [How to start playwright outside 'with' without context managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73043207/how-to-start-playwright-outside-with-without-context-managers) and [can i run playwright outside of 'with'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72653869/can-i-run-playwright-outside-of-with)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start playwright outside 'with' without context managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73043207/how-to-start-playwright-outside-with-without-context-managers)